# How to make a PyQt Progress Bar that doesn't start from zero

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, progress-bar, loading

It always starts fro zero, but I want to make a loading bar 
[Just like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qpy6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation.

> If minimum and maximum both are set to 0, the bar shows a busy indicator instead of a percentage of steps